# Custom EmailValidator doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a custom email validator class based on the ruby guide:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
     record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end
```

This class is located in app/validators/email_validator.rb

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :name, :email, presence: true
validates :email, email: true

end
```

Error:

```
`rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator' (ArgumentError)
```

This error comes up when running tests (rspec).

Comment: @pavan see this ... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: Probably a silly question, but you have stopped and started your development server and/or rails console?

Comment: That is where I found this validator in the first place. Not a silly question at all, I'm a beginner so I might do weird/stupid mistakes. I get this error running rspec though, so no server running in the first place

Comment: Thanks manu. Would I need to add something to the development environment in order for the validation file to load correctly?

Comment: That is the problem. There's nothing to be added anywhere. I didn't have to. Just scaffolded my way through and added the validators. Worked fine :P

Comment: I also haven't done much yet, I just started on this application and have only two models with only validations so far and tests for the models. So I haven't changed anything in configuration files or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    begin
      r =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
    rescue Exception => e
      r = false
    end
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email") unless r
end
```

**Pro tip:**

it looks like you are looking for email validator, why not you use this one

```
require 'mail'
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
    begin
      m = Mail::Address.new(value)
      # We must check that value contains a domain and that value is an email address
      r = m.domain && m.address == value
      t = m.__send__(:tree)
      # We need to dig into treetop
      # A valid domain must have dot_atom_text elements size > 1
      # user@localhost is excluded
      # treetop must respond to domain
      # We exclude valid email values like <user@localhost.com>
      # Hence we use m.__send__(tree).domain
      r &&= (t.domain.dot_atom_text.elements.size > 1)
    rescue Exception => e   
      r = false
    end
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid") unless r
  end
end
```

Be sure to load this class before, i guess you know to do it (as many other answer already described it in a good way)

Comment: This validator loads just fine! Thank you. Still do not know why the original validator doesn't work, which bothers me a bit but atleast I have the validation :)

Comment: The error you're rescuing is because of a malformed `=~` statement, see my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

I just had this problem, and here's the real solution.

It turns out that copying and pasting code from the Rails docs may leave you with mixed space characters that will cause your code to parse incorrectly. Here's [a sample gist diff of an original and corrected version of my validator](https://gist.github.com/fny/dbd3d7d5eb88eb65174b/revisions). Notice everything looks the same, but somehow there's a diff! If you run the first version, you'll get the same error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'record' for WholeNumberValidator:Class
```

If we inspect the bytes, we see the difference:

```
# Standard Space
' '.bytes # => [32]: U+0020, Space
# Space from Copy/Paste
' '.bytes # => [194, 160]: U+00A0, No break space
```

Replace the spaces in the file, and everything should work!

Comment: Thanks, this was beyond frustrating. What a bizarre bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should definitely be the accepted answer! I wonder what is the solution for fixing the character encoding on the Rails Guides site to avoid this issue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions to this problem. The issue is that your `EmailValidator` is not on the load path so Rails doesn't know how to find it. Any one of the solutions below should work:

1. require the `email_validator` explicitly in the file you want to use it or maybe even inside of an initializer like so:

   ```
   # config/initializers/validators.rb
   require "#{Rails.root}/app/validators/email_validator"
   ```
2. Add the `validators` directory to your application's autoload path:

   ```
   # config/application.rb
   config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]
   ```
3. Place your `email_validator` inside of a directory where it is already on the autoload path like `app/models/email_validator.rb` or `lib/email_validator.rb`

Personally, #2 is my preferred solution since it provides a nice structure to your app by designating a specific directory for validators and you won't need to change any code in the future when adding new validators.

Comment: Thanks Hamed, #2 makes no difference, but #1 actually changed something at least. Now the error is the following: `<class:EmailValidator>': undefined local variable or method `record' for EmailValidator:Class (NameError)

Comment: That is strange. I don't see anything wrong in your validator code. `record` is clearly provided as a method parameter so I don't understand why it would be undefined.

Comment: I just realised, your regex matcher is backwards... I know that's what's in the document but the =~ documentation is here... http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E

Which implies you should have...
unless /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i =~ value

Comment: Further note... if the =~ is structured incorrectly (as yours is) the documentation says you'll get an "undefined local variable or method" error (which you do!)  So fix the =~ as per my previous comment, and with Hamed's solution #1 you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

To make this directory `app/validators/` visible for rails autoloader, you need to add it to `application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb

# ...

# add custom validators path
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]
```

And restart your rails server

Comment: The error comes when running rspec, so I don't have a server even running.

Comment: I also thought about this initially, but it seems autoloading paths for validators is optional. (??)

Comment: Edited and added that the error appears when running tests. And the load path should be optional, and adding it to application.rb do not make any difference either.

Comment: I'd always thought that all classes under "app" were loaded automatically. :(

Answer (score 0):

I note that Hamed's solution #1 partially worked for you, but you get "undefined local variable or method"

This is the error if you try putting a variable on the left side of the `=~` comparison operator.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E

the correct format for the unless is

```
unless /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i =~ value
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your solution as well with no luck. Luckily Paritosh's Validator worked like a charm!

Comment: Well, glad you got a solution! Just to be clear, then... the validator is working properly?  Correct email addresses are accepted and invalid email addresses are rejected?  If that's so, I need to update my learning!

Comment: I'm not saying that you weren't correct with your answer, I think the problem was on my end. I used the other validator that was posted by Paritosh Piplewar. And yes that validator work corretly. With your suggestion I still got the same errors

Comment: Hi, thanks, that clarified for me.  And the Paritosh other validator looks pretty neat. :)  Cheers